Azuma-Hoeffding for one-side bounded super-martingale sequence
Suppose we have a real-valued super-martingale difference sequence $\{X_k\}$ w.r.t. some filtration $\mathcal{F_k}$, i.e., $X_k$ is $\mathcal{F_k}$-measurable, and
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_k|\mathcal{F}_{k-1}] \leq 0.$$
The difference sequence is bounded from above as $X_k \leq d, \forall k$, where $d >0$. However, the sequence need not be bounded from below - this is the key departure from the standard Azuma-Hoeffding setup. Is the following Azuma-Hoeffding-like inequality then true?
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_k \geq t\right) \leq c_1 \exp\left(-c_2 \frac{t^2}{N d^2}\right),\quad \forall t > 0, $$
where $c_1, c_2 > 0$ are some universal constants. It would seem so since the $X_k$'s being negative would only make it harder for the sum to exceed $t$.

This seems to be the third variation of the same question you've rapidly asked over the course of the last few hours.

This was the original question I had in mind, and I am not sure the answer to the first variant provides an answer to the version above. The reason is that the standard Azuma-Hoeffding proof requires providing a bound on the moment-generating function.

This is not true.  For instance take $X_k$ to be independent with $X_k = 1/2$ with probability $1 - 1/2^k$ and $-2^k$ with probability $1/2^k$.  Then $\mathbb{E} X_k < 0$ but $$\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^N X_k}{N} \to \frac{1}{2}$$ almost surely by Borel-Cantelli.  This contradicts your desired bound.
In particular you need some kind of control to say that the assumption that $(X_k)_k$ is a (sub/super or usual) martingale doesn't come from integrating rare events.  There is a fantastic survey by Chung and Lu that has a huge number of martingale inequalities, including one-sided versions.  Still, even in one-sided cases there has to be some control on the size of $X_k$ otherwise the martingale assumption says little about the typical case.

Thanks for this counter-example! I am aware of the survey paper by Chung and Lu. In Section 8 of their book, they do indeed have results for "almost martingales," where the uniform bounds on the martingale increments only hold with high probability. The issue is that all these results are derived for discrete/finite probability spaces, since the applications mostly pertain to computer science problems/graph processes where considering discrete spaces suffices. I am trying to find similar results for scenarios where the outcome space can be real-valued.
